# I'm confused as to which resistors you include when calculating τ=RC, in an RC circuit?

Tags: circuits

In example 7.14, how come the Rf resistor is not part of the RC circuit...that is, why don't we need to include Rf when finding the time constant (RC)?

[image]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: HINT: The input resistor represents a source impedance and is not part of the integral equation. In most cases only Rf and C count.

Comment: More people will actually read your question if you clip the images to just show the schematics you're asking about. As is, the images are unreadable, and many of us will not be interested in clicking through to enlarge them.

Comment: Should the title read "tau", \$ \tau \$?

Answer (score 1):

If you compute the Z<sub>f</sub>/Z<sub>in</sub> transfer function, you can see that when Z<sub>c</sub>=R<sub>f</sub>, you have reached the -3dB breakpoint ω, which is related to τ.

The equivalent rise time is τ=RC=1/ω.

Since the inverting input is a virtual AC ground, each side of the node (Z<sub>f</sub> and Z<sub>in</sub>) is independent and superposition applies in the linear range.

e.g.   \$R_{in}*C_{in}=1/ω_o = τ\$ and R<sub>f</sub>/R<sub>in</sub>= high frequency gain when Z<sub>c</sub>=0 for the high pass filter with gain.

Comment: Please double-check my edits, and rollback or modify if needed. In the last sentence, did you mean low pass? I left it as is, in case you were referring to a different circuit (especially since there is no C_in, for the circuit I was looking at).

Comment: @BlairFonville read my answer again.  C input is in the denominator so it is HPF.  Rf is isolated between Vout and AC virtual ground so it only affects HF gain when Zc(f)<<Rin. ie when f is above breakpoint

Comment: Ok. I see that now. The OP’s book pages are a little ambiguous. My assumption is that the question was in reference to the figure on the page on the right-side (Figure 7.56 for problem 7.14) which is low-pass integrator. I’m guessing you were referring to the differentiator on the left.